# How to solve enterprise recaptcha

Tags: python, recaptcha, 2captcha

The captcha I'm trying to solve with 2captcha is like this-

Step 1) You input something

Step 2) You press continue and then it goes let's say page 2

Step 3) In the page 2 you'll see the captcha the page URL doesn't change at all

Step 4) How to solve this? I found the site key, but it doesn't solve because you'll have to press continue first...

The code

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))

from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

api_key = 'api_key here'

solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)

try:
    result = solver.recaptcha(
        sitekey='site_key',
        url='url',
        invisible=0,
        enterprise=1
        )

except Exception as e:
    sys.exit(e)

else:
    sys.exit('result: ' + str(result))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.